# how to use border space on 2 td side by side?

Tags: css

So I have 2 td side by side in a table. The first td has a border, the second doesn't but the element inside has one and I need both border to line up (top and bottom)

So is there a way to have the element go "over" the border space since it's not there? If I try to grow the element inside the td, the td grows and keep a 1px border spacing even if it's not there.

Rough html:

```
<table><tr>
<td class="border">1</td><td class="noborder"><span class="border">Text</span></td>
</tr></table>
```

See this fiddle for a better picture :)
http://jsfiddle.net/LcGks/1/

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do will make the content height of td different for first and second td. In table all element in a row have same height so i think you should not use table for this.

Otherwise the workaround i can think for this is to apply top and bottom border for td.noborder which will make both td's line up.

like this

```
td.noborder {
    border: solid blue;
    border-width: 1px 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

see here http://jsfiddle.net/LcGks/1/

Answer (score 0):

I usually do this using the `cellspacing` attribute of the table.

```
<table cellspacing="2px" border="1px">
    <tr>
    <td class="border">1</td><td class="noborder"><span class="border">Text</span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

see example: [here](http://phpfiddle.org/api/run/4ab-s7n) and see [Code](http://phpfiddle.org/api/raw/4ab-s7n)

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use box-sizing on table elements, I don't really see an easy way out. I think the best way would be to use a div inside the table cell to display the border.

- http://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing